# JPA 2: mapping a map where the key is an entity, value is Boolean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

We are trying to map a relation where an entity has a map where the key is another entity and the value is a Boolean:

```
    @Id Long id;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "APPROVALS_PRODUCT_APPROVALS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_APPROVAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @Column(name = "EXCLUDED")
    private Map<Approval, Boolean> approvals = new HashMap<Approval, Boolean>();
```

For some reason, Eclipselink gives a BigDecimal for each value in the map, instead of Boolean.

```
approvals.get(testApproval); // returns a BigDecimal :-(
```

Is there anything that doesn't look right? Is this us, or is this a bug in Eclipselink?

EDIT:
Tried this (Approval has 2 @Id fields):

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "APPROVALS_PRODUCT_APPROVALS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_APPROVAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @Column(name = "EXCLUDED")
    @MapKeyJoinColumns({ @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_VALUE", referencedColumnName = "CREDENTIAL_VALUE"), @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE") })
    private Map<Approval, Boolean> approvals = new HashMap<Approval, Boolean>();
```

and got the same result (BigDecimal instead of Boolean)

EDIT2:
We are using Eclipselink 2.3.0, also tried with 2.3.2 with same result.

Comment: That is completely bizarre. Definitely looks like a bug to me. What's the DDL for the `APPROVALS_PRODUCT_APPROVALS` table?

Comment: @ymajoros map work fine with Boolean and i think there is no bugs in Eclipselink. i have tried this in eclipse.can you post your iterator code for approvals key set.

Comment: @Tom table is generated by eclipselink at start

Comment: @Riddhish There is definitely some problem with that. I don't even have an iterator, just did a approvals.get(someApproval) and had a BigDecimal instance. Using Eclipselink 2.1.1

Comment: JPA doesn't define support for Map where the Key is Entity and the value not.

Comment: @DataNucleus http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html example 2 seems to imply that it is possible. We tried specifying MapKeyJoinColumn but got a weird error about missing JoinColumns

Comment: @ymajoros Yes, you're right, my mistake. The spec is glib on too many points and leaves too much to interpretation or coming across things in the javadoc. Just tried the same snippet on DataNucleus JPA and works fine (didn't bother with the MapKeyJoinColumn)

Comment: It seems that we are using EL 2.3.0 (Glassfish 3.1.1). Upgrading to 2.3.2 had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong,

targetClass on ElementCollection is for specifying an Embeddable class (if generics are not used), so should be not used.

You also need a @MapKeyJoinColumn if you want the Map key to be another object (or @MapKeyClass if it is an Embeddable.

Most databases do not have a Boolean type, so booleans are normally stored as numbers, 0/1.  So you may be missing a conversion somehow.  You can define an @Convert with a @TypeConverter for this, although it should be getting defaulted, so you may log a bug for that.

Comment: Ok, used Converter / Convert. Only problem is, this is Eclipselink specific and this is forbidden in our project. Guess I'll log a bug. Any idea on a chance to get a standard Convert annotation in next JPA revision?